# Ruby: how to concat two return values to two strings in one line

Tags: ruby

I am trying to `concat` two strings that are returned by a function to two existing strings in one line.

this is my code with extra steps

```
def my_function()
    return "foo", "bar"
end

foo = String.new
bar = String.new
ret1, ret2 = my_function()
foo.concat(ret1)
bar.concat(ret2)
```

I am trying something like the following, but it is not working

```
foo.concat(ret1), bar.concat(ret2) = my_function()
```

some more information as requested:

I am basically trying to write a config converter. The config files need to be plain text files. To make the code more structured, i created the following module, and then call the module functions whenever i need to genereate a specific part of the config. After that, I write the return into a string, which is then written to a file once everything is done:

```
module L4_LB
    extend self
    def build_ssl(some_vars)
        returns string_a, string_b
    end
    def build_vip(some_vars)
        returns string_a, string_b
    end
    def build_pool(some_vars)
        returns string_a, string_b
    end
end
    
config_file_a = String.new
config_file_b = String.new

ret_a, ret_b = L4_LB.build_ssl(some_vars)
config_file_a.concat(ret_a)
config_file_a.concat(ret_b)

ret_a, ret_b = L4_LB.build_vip(some_vars)
config_file_a.concat(ret_a)
config_file_a.concat(ret_b)

ret_a, ret_b = L4_LB.build_pool(some_vars)
config_file_a.concat(ret_a)
config_file_a.concat(ret_b)
```

Comment: `[foo, bar].zip(my_function) { |a, b| a.concat(b) }` would work, but I don't see any advantage over your 3 simple lines.

Comment: I have a couple of functions which build plain text configs, and return it as strings. if I need to call 10 of those functions, i always need to add those lines to collect the different snippets in one string, which I can then write into a file. would love to make it more readable..

Comment: I don't understand why you have to concatenate the return values to different strings in the first place. Can you provide a more complete example that shows how you build such configs? Maybe there's a simpler or more elegant approach to your problem.

Comment: Can you explain why each of the methods returns two values? Since the return values seem to end up in separate config files, I'd probably also have separate `a`/ `b` methods, i.e. `config_file_a << build_ssl_a(...)` or maybe pass an argument for the variant, i.e. `config_file_a << build_ssl(:a, ...)`.

Comment: the methods generate the config based on the "some_vars" input, which is the same for both return values. I also have a dependency, so if I split it into two methods, I would need to make sure that I always run both methods

Comment: You could change the methods to write to both strings right-away. Create a class via `config_builder = L4_LB.new(config_a, config_b)` and then call `config_builder.build_ssl` which then appends to `config_a` and `config_b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how `concat` is defined. If it accepts multiple arguments, you should be able to do:

```
config_file_a.concat(*L4_LB.build_pool(some_vars))
```

Note the `*` which ensures that each element in the array returned by `build_pool` is passed as an individual argument to concat.

On the other hand, if `concat` only accepts a single argument you can define a helper function:

```
def my_concat(what, values)
  values.each do |element|
    what.concat(element)
  end
end

my_concat(config_file_a, L4_LB.build_pool(some_vars))
```

If you want the result to be concatenated to two different strings, you could use:

```
def my_concat2(cs, vs)
  cs.each_with_index do |c, index|
    c.concat(vs[index])
  end
end

cs = [config_file_a, config_file_b]
my_concat2(cs, *L4_LB.build_ssl(some_vars))
my_concat2(cs, *L4_LB.build_vip(some_vars))
my_concat2(cs, *L4_LB.build_pool(some_vars))
```

Comment: https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/String/concat

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that it was `concat` fron the `String` class that was used.

Comment: this is a great approach, thanks a lot